# Dynamic way to get JSON attributes?

Tags: python, json

My first dabble with Python and JSON.
In the example below, I am loading JSON data and writing the values to a text file.

Is it possible to output the attribute names (`name`, `role`, and `ID`) as the first line of the text file? Obviously I could hard code the attributes (or column names as that is what I am after), but wondered if there was a more dynamic way to do this....what if I don't know the attribute names?

```
resp = reqSession.get(url, headers=head, verify=False)
json_data = json.loads(resp.text)

file = open("testfile.txt","w")
file.write("There are currently " + str(len(json_data)) + " USERS in " + model + "\n")

for users in json_data:
    #print(users["name"] + "," + users["role"] + "," + users["id"])
    file.write(users["name"] + "," + users["role"] + "," + users["id"] + "\n")
file.close()
```

Comment: What is `reqSession`? Also you should look into the `csv` module.  `csv.DictWriter` does this for you.

Comment: You can access the keys of a dictionary with... `.keys()`. But yes, the [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) is probably what you're looking for, it will help you deal with ordering issues etc.

Comment: instead of open and close try using the `with` statement - http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python

Comment: If you add sample JSON data then folks may be able give you more concrete answer. Alternately, add the code to get the data from a url that others can also use for testing.

Answer (score 0):

An object within a JSON string parsed via `json.loads` will be converted into a dictionary, thus all you need to do in order to iterate through the object and write their values is the following

```
for key, value in json_data.items():
    file.write("{}: {}\n".format(key, value)
```

If you only want to write the values, as shown in your example, you could also do something like this